# Spliting Kotlin2JavaScript code into several maven modules

Tags: kotlin

I have three modules: client, share, server.

Server is a "normal" Kotlin module, compiled to JVM ByteCode. 
Share should be compiled to JS and to JVM ByteCod
Client compiles only to JS.

I have setup share to compile JS and ByteCode - this works fine. The problem is, that the client module cannnot be compiled because it doesn't see the classes from client.

Kotlin Code:

```
import com.a.typical.super.long.package.which.contains.ModelId

interface ClientOrca {

  fun test(): ModelId
}

[ERROR] <ClientKt>:[1,8] Unresolved reference: com
[ERROR] <ClientKt>:[5,15] Unresolved reference: ModelId
```

How can I setup a project (with maven) so that my code, which is splitted into several maven modules, is compiled in one-go to one JS file?

Comment: See how it is done in https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.html, for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is indeed in the [github examples](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/examples) of kotlin. Here is a summary:

1. The library has to produce a jar file containing the js files and the *.class files. To achieve this you have to tell the kotlin compiler to produce js files and put them into the class folder and also compile all kotlin files to *.class files in the class directory (target/classes)

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
           <artifactId>kotlin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>compile</id>
                   <phase>compile</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>js</goal>
                       <goal>compile</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <sourceDirs>
                           <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/kotlin</sourceDir>
                           <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDir>
                       </sourceDirs>
                       <outputFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/${project.artifactId}.js</outputFile>  <!-- super important! -->
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
               <execution>
                   <id>test-compile</id>
                   <phase>test-compile</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>test-js</goal>
                       <goal>test-compile</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <sourceDirs>
                           <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/kotlin</sourceDir>
                           <sourceDir>${project.basedir}/src/test/java</sourceDir>
                       </sourceDirs>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
           <!-- Insert these lines -->
           <configuration>
               <moduleKind>commonjs</moduleKind>
           </configuration>
           <!-- end of inserted text -->
       </plugin>
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>3.0.2</version>
           <configuration>
               <forceCreation>true</forceCreation>
               <includes>
                   <include>**/*</include>
               </includes>
               <archive>
                   <forced/>
                   <manifestEntries>
                       <Built-By>Me</Built-By>
                       <Implementation-Vendor>Me</Implementation-Vendor>
                       <Implementation-Version>1.0.0</Implementation-Version>
                   </manifestEntries>
               </archive>
           </configuration>
       </plugin>
   ```
2. In the js project which uses the library you have to tell maven to unpack the dependency and make the js files available. Change the pom.xml the following way:

   ```
       <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
           <executions>
               <execution>
                   <id>unpack</id>
                   <phase>compile</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>unpack</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <artifactItems>
                           <artifactItem>
                               <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlin</groupId>
                               <artifactId>kotlin-stdlib-js</artifactId>
                               <version>${kotlin.version}</version>
                               <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/js/lib</outputDirectory>
                               <includes>*.js</includes>
                           </artifactItem>
                           <artifactItem>
                               <groupId>ch.viseon.openOrca</groupId>
                               <artifactId>share</artifactId>
                               <version>${project.version}</version>
                               <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/js/lib</outputDirectory>
                               <includes>*.js</includes>
                           </artifactItem>
                       </artifactItems>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   ```